# Secure Equals: Why is inequality still consistently less time?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, c#-4.0, timing

I have a method that compares two byte arrays for equality, with the major caveat that it does not fail and exit early when it detects inequality.  Basically the code is used to compare Cross-Site Request Forgery tokens, and avoid (as much as possible) the ability to use timing to hack the key.  I wish I could find the link to the paper that discusses the attack in detail, but the important thing is that the code I have still has a statistically measurable bias for returning sooner if the two byte arrays are equal--although it is an order of magnitude better.  So without further ado, here is the code:

```
public static bool SecureEquals(byte[] original, byte[] potential)
{
    // They should be the same size, but we don't want to throw an
    // exception if we are wrong.
    bool isEqual = original.Length == potential.Length;
    int maxLenth = Math.Max(original.Length, potential.Length);

    for(int i=0; i < maxLength; i++)
    {
        byte originalByte = (i < original.Length) ? original[i] : (byte)0;
        byte potentialByte = (i < potential.Length) ? potential[i] : (byte)0;

        isEqual = isEqual && (originalByte == potentialByte);
    }

    return isEqual;
}
```

The difference in average timing between equal and unequal tokens is consistently 10-25ms (depending on garbage collection cycles) shorter for unequal tokens.  This is precisely what I want to avoid.  If the relative timing were equal, or the average timing swapped based on the run I would be happy.  The problem is that we are consistently running shorter for unequal tokens.  In contrast, if we stopped the loop on the first unequal token, we could have up to an 80x difference in timing.

While this equality check is a major improvement over the typical eager return, it is still not good enough.  Essentially, I don't want any *consistent* result for equality or inequality returning faster.  If I could get the results into the range where garbage collection cycles will mask any consistent bias, I will be happy.

Anyone have a clue what is causing the timing bias toward inequality being faster?  At first I thought it was the ternary operator returning an access to the array or a constant if the arrays were of unequal size.  The problem is that I still get this bias if the two arrays are the same size.

NOTE: As requested, the links to the articals on Timing Attacks:

- http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/ssl-timing.pdf (official paper, linked to from the blog post below)
- http://codahale.com/a-lesson-in-timing-attacks/  (talks about the failure in Java's library)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack (more general, but not as complete)

Comment: Please do find the link to that paper. Sounds interesting.

Comment: Here's some articles to get you started: http://codahale.com/a-lesson-in-timing-attacks/  and  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack

Comment: I would suggest something like `byte differences = 0; for(int i=0; i < minLength; i++) differences |= original[i] ^ potential[i];` and figure the arrays are equal only if the lengths match and `differences` is zero.  That should yield timings which are independent of the values stored in the arrays, no matter how the system's cache behaves.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This line *could* be causing a problem:

```
isEqual = isEqual && (originalByte == potentialByte);
```

That won't bother evaluating the `originalByte == potentialByte` subexpression if `isEquals` is already false. You don't want the shortcircuiting here, so change it to:

```
isEqual = isEqual & (originalByte == potentialByte);
```

EDIT: Note that you're already effectively leaking the information about the size of the original data - because it will always run in a constant time until the `potential` array exceeds the `original` array in size, at which point the time will increase. It's probably quite tricky to avoid this... so I would go for the "throw an exception if they're not the right size" approach which explicitly acknowledges it, effectively.

EDIT: Just to go over the idea I included in comments:

```
// Let's assume you'll never really need more than this
private static readonly byte[] LargeJunkArray = new byte[1024 * 32];

public static bool SecureEquals(byte[] original, byte[] potential)
{
    // Reveal that the original array will never be more than 32K.
    // This is unlikely to be particularly useful.
    if (potential.Length > LargeJunkArray.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }
    byte[] copy = new byte[potential.Length];
    int bytesFromOriginal = Math.Min(original.Length, copy.Length);
    // Always copy the same amount of data
    Array.Copy(original, 0, copy, 0, bytesFromOriginal);
    Array.Copy(LargeJunkArray, 0, copy, bytesFromOriginal,
               copy.Length - bytesFromOriginal);

    bool isEqual = original.Length == potential.Length;
    for(int i=0; i < copy.Length; i++)
    {
        isEqual = isEqual & (copy[i] == potential[i]);
    }

    return isEqual;
}
```

Note that this assumes that `Array.Copy` will take the same amount of time to copy the same amount of data from any source - that may well not be true, based on CPU caches...

Comment: @SwDev: no but that’s not the point. Using bitwise operation just suppresses the short-circuiting, e.g. the fact that the right-hand side of the `&&` expression won’t be evaluated once `isEquals` is `false`.

Comment: @Konrad - Yeah just saw that, I would probably put a conditional check at the start.  The loop doesnt need to run if the lengths are not equal to start with or you hit the first different character. (ex `(i < maxLength) && isEqual`)

Comment: @SwDevMan81: You seem to be missing the point. We want to do the same amount of work however incorrect the data is.

Comment: I've given a lot of thought about the leaking the size of the key problem.  I may have to process a consistent number of bytes regardless of key size.  The code I have does allow me to increase the key size without changing the number of bytes evaluated.

Comment: @Berin: If you don't mind inefficiency you could always create a new array of the size of "potential", then copy "original" into it, then copy from some junk array into the rest (so that you always copy the same amount of data) before performing the comparison.

Comment: @Jon: Out of curiosity, do you happen to know if the compiler and/or jitter are allowed to short-circuit an `&` if static analysis can prove that skipping the second clause has no side-effects and will never change the result? I'd assume that they could, although whether they actually do is another matter. And I'd also assume that execution time doesn't qualify as a side-effect since it's dependent on so many variables anyway.

Comment: @LukeH: I don't know, to be honest. Given how platform-specific this sort of thing is, I would test it on every platform you're going to deploy it on.

Comment: I've just tested this, and that is what the problem was.  Just one character....  I've anotated the code to demonstrate it's need.  The variations are all less than 1ms, and sometimes equality is faster and sometimes inequality is faster.  Exactly what's necessary.

Comment: The `&` is a bitwise operator. instead of a logical one.  The method I used to test this is to collect a mean for execution times over a statistically significant number (1000 samples worked to produce the consistency).  I did have to run the test multiple times to determine if the average difference was always biased one way or the other.  NOTE: I introduced a constant (larger than my CSRF token) for the number of cells to compare.  I also introduced a test to verify that any change in the CSRF token algorithm doesn't exceed that constant.

Comment: @Berin: The `&` operator is a logical operator when applied to boolean operands, no different to `&&` (except, obviously, for the non-short-circuiting aspect). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx

Comment: The most important part is that I get consistent timing.  I don't want the short-circuiting effect in this case.

Comment: @Jon, in your edited code you introduced an O(n) timing dependency.  Array.Copy timing increases linearly with the size of the array.  The goal of the algorithm is to provide O(1) timing (i.e. constant).  Using `&` and providing a constant number to replace `maxLength` in my code gave me that.

Comment: @Berin: The timing dependency is only based on the length of `potential`. I assumed this was provided by the possible attacker... as they already know the length, it doesn't give them any information. To put it another way: if I ask you to guess what number I'm thinking of, and then take a time proportional to *your guess* to tell you whether or not you're right, that doesn't tell you anything about the number I'm thinking of.

Comment: @Jon: Your example is missing a declaration for `isEqual`.  Maybe something like `bool isEqual = original.Length == potential.Length;` .

Answer (score 4):

In the event that .NET should be smart enough to optimize this out – have you tried introducing a counter variable that counts the number of unequal characters, and returns true if and only if that number is zero?

```
public static bool SecureEquals(byte[] original, byte[] potential)
{
    // They should be the same size, but we don't want to throw an
    // exception if we are wrong.
    int maxLength = Math.Max(original.Length, potential.Length);
    int equals = maxLength - Math.Min(original.Length, potential.Length);

    for(int i=0; i < maxLength; i++)
    {
        byte originalByte = (i < original.Length) ? original[i] : (byte)0;
        byte potentialByte = (i < potential.Length) ? potential[i] : (byte)0;

        equals += originalByte != potentialByte ? 1 : 0;
    }

    return equals == 0;
}
```

Comment: This might be clearer in the long term.  I'll definitely consider it.

Comment: +1 For a simpler implementation.  There are far fewer places a timing hole could hide in this code.

Comment: I think there is an information leak if the attack has a way to call `SecureEquals` while in control of the length of one side, since he can then determine the value of `maxLength` without knowing the length of both sides.  So, you should only loop through iterations equal to the length of one of the two parameters (whichever one is provided by the attacker), and should also call `equals += originalByte.Length != potentialByte.Length ? 1 : 0`.

Comment: @Brian: that is correct. My code merely strove to fix the weakness noticed by the OP. I am *not qualified* to comment on other security issues. But the problem you discovered has already been outlined (and fixed?) in Jon’s answer, which is why his is the accepted answer, not mine.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea what is causing the difference -- a profiler seems like it would be a good tool to have here. But I'd consider going with a different approach altogether.

What I'd do in this situation is build a timer into the method so that it can measure its own timing when given two equal keys. (Use the Stopwatch class.) It should compute the mean and standard deviation of the success timing and stash that away in some global state. When you get an unequal key, you can then measure how much time it took you to detect the unequal key, and then make up the difference by spinning a tight loop until the appropriate amount of time has elapsed. You can choose a random time to spin consistent with a normal distribution based on the mean and standard deviation you've already computed.

The nice thing about this approach is that now you have a general mechanism that you can re-use when defeating other timing attacks, and the meaning of the code is obvious; no one is going to come along and try to optimize it away.

And like any other "Security" code, get it reviewed by a security professional before you ship it.

Comment: The risk with this approach is that inequality has a statistically discernable _increase_ in time in comparison to equality.  Any change in timing with a consistent bias makes the code vulnerable to timing attacks.  My test harness has the Stopwatch class, and runs the code enough times to uncover the bias in mean timings.  The timings I am testing for are strict enough that they will fail if someone changes the operator, but loose enough they won't intermittently fail on the integration test server.

Comment: I've written enough multi-threaded code to know you can't rely on `Thread.Sleep()` for this purpose which is what would be needed to avoid unruly processor utilization on a simple spin loop.

Comment: @Berin: Right, you do *not* want to introduce a delay by sleeping because *the attacker might be measuring processor utilization as well as time*. If the attacker can determine that there is time passing without processor utilization then they can deduce that you are waiting to try to fool them, not because you have real work to do.

Comment: @Berin: also, it occurs to me that you probably want to artificially add extra time when the keys are equal.